# Taxonomy term View Customization

Tags: taxonomy-terms

on a website I'm working this period i have this problem with Taxonomy term View:
My scenario is like this : I've created a vocabulary with terms and sub-terms for my products categories. So for example there is a structure like this:

First Category: Computing-->Laptops (Apple, Acer, Dell)-->
 Desktops (CPU, RAM, Hard Drives, VGA)--> Servers (HP, Dell, Cisco, IBM)

Second Category:Peripherals--> Monitors (Samsung, LG,Dell, Asus)-->Keyboards (Logitech, Microsoft)--> Printers (Epson, HP, Samsung)

I'm using taxonomy term view to make the taxonomy term page to show the products in a grid using fields. Everything works fine, when i click for example on Dell i see XPS14, XPS14Z, XPS15 etc in a grid format with a thumbnail picture and the title below it. (I' created a field for thumbnail for every product).

What i want to do is when i click on Computing for example, to show only Laptops, Desktops and Servers with a thumbnail for each one and not all the products for Computing term ( Apple,Acer,Dell,CPU,RAM,Hard Drives...etc) as it happens now. I've tried to put some contextual filters from the view but i didn't figured out how to accomplish it yet.

Comment: What is the second category for? Do product belong to the first AND second category? Under Computing > Laptops there is Apple, Acer and Dell. Are these child taxonomy terms or nodes?

Comment: Sorry, that i didn't make it clear. Products belongs only to one category and these are child taxonomy terms eg Term 1 Computing --> child sub term Laptops --> child sub term Apple etc. For example there is product XPS15 that is tagged with Dell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally find the solution.

Step 1, I added an image field for thumbnails to my taxonomy vocabulary and uploaded thumbnail image to each term.

Step 2, I created a new view showing taxonomy terms with these settings:
Title: %1, Path : taxonomy/term/%, Format:Grid, Show :Fields (Taxonomy thumbnail image, Taxonomy Name), Contextual Filters:  Taxonomy term: Parent term (When the filter value is NOT in the URL--> Provide default value -->Taxonomy term ID from URL and checked "Load default filter from term page ").

Step 3 I enable default taxonomy term view i made these changes :
Title: %1, Path : taxonomy/term/%, Format: Grid, Show: Fields (Title, Thumbnail), Contextual Filters:  Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)(Depth: -1), No results behavior: Global: View area(View to insert : The view created in Step 1)).

And that's it.

(Felix thanks for the inspiration)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are using the "Taxonomy term" view that comes with drupal.

Edit that view and:

1. Edit the contextual filter for "Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)"
   [image]
2. Set the depth option as high as you need to cover the number of levels in your vocabulary.
   [image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I've already tried this and the result was not what i want. Changing the depth just reduce or increase the depth of parent terms showed, so if i change it to 2 then clicking on computing will show all the products in computing e.g all the laptops products, all the cpu products, all the rams, all the servers etc. I just whant on clicking Computing to show categories Laptops, Desktops, Servers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution here is going to be to use the pre-made taxonomy term pages to list the products, but use custom views to list categories.

If you make a new view that shows taxonomy terms from the computing vocabulary, and then add a filter so that parent term = 0 then it will list Laptops, Desktops, Servers. When these titles are clicked then they will link to the normal taxonomy term listing page.